# Add() method in AbstractCollection class

Tags: java, collections, return

This is a piece of `AbstractCollection<E>` class:

```
public boolean addAllm(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    boolean modified = false;
    for (E e : c)
        if (add(e))
            modified = true;
    return modified;
}
public boolean add(E e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Is there any situation when method `add(E e)` returns value "false" and hence `addAll` method returns "false"?

By the way I always thought that when one method is of any type it should include return statement (with except for "void"). So, my next question is:

Are there any other situations when methods in java return value of one type without use of statement `return` or `throw new ...Exception()` like in the example above?

Sorry for my English, if something is unclear..

Comment: If `e` is already in the collection and if the collection does not accept duplicates, it can return false.

Comment: `Set` is also collection so its `add` can return `false` if it already contains element. Also please post one question per post.

Comment: Regarding the last part, both methods return or throw, so I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an abstract class.

If you use the `add` method as provided (directly or via `addAll`), it will just fail with an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Subclasses will want to provide their own `add` method (that actually does something useful).

Those are supposed to return `true` or `false` depending on if the element was added or not (for example a Set will not allow duplicates).

As for method return values in general, the compiler makes sure that a method always returns a value of the declared return type (or returns without a value for `void` methods) or throws an exception. It won't let you have methods that can end without that (*)

(*) you can have methods that don't end at all ...

Answer (score 0):

Some collections may refuse insertion, for example Set are meant to contain unique elements and will remain unchanged and return false if an element they already contain is added to them.

Constructors have implicit return, I think that's the only other way to exit a function with a return type different from void.